# What is the proper way to bind & deploy a hibernate 4 project with a web application?

Tags: hibernate, deployment, jboss, vaadin, myeclipse

I am trying to figure out how to properly utilize hibernate 4 from a web project (a Vaadin 7 project in my case). I am using eclipse and the Vaadin web project (before trying to access hibernate stuff) deploys and runs properly on my jBoss EAP.

All the tutorials for hibernate point you to how to add the hibernate tools in eclipse (did that) then create a Java Project then add hibernate facet (this is what MyEclipse call it) to the project and then reverse engineer your tables into POJO classes with annotations and everything. At that point it also creates the hibernate.cfg.xml and the whole project compiles fine.

Then I add the hibernate project as a dependency on the Vaadin web project in order to be able to get the hibernate session and start loading stuff through the pojos.

My problem is that I can not figure out how to deploy the hibernate project on jBoss in order for the web project to "see it". Both compile fine in eclipse, however, I get ClassNotFound errors (for hibernate classes) when I try to run the web project.

Is my whole approach wrong? Should the web (vaadin) project and the hibernate project be one?

Thanks in advance for any assistance.

Best Regards

Comment: [...]I add the hibernate project as a dependency on the Vaadin web project[...] what do you mean by that exactly?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Vaadin but are the hibernate project classes deployed, when you deploy the Vaadin project? That is, do you see them in the deployment location (either as a jar file or merged into the classes folder? If not you may need to change your deployment settings for the project and how to do that varies with the MyEclipse release. If using 2013 or 2014, use the deployment assembly (shown in the project properties) to define dependencies, rather than defining them in the build path configuration.

Comment: @TonyWeddle I found where to define deployment options in MyEclipse. That almost helped (it deploys the jars that are dependencies in the hibernate project in /lib/lib - it adds an extra lib folder) and I do not know how to avoid it. However, when I move the jars by hand it works and I do not get any NoClassDef errors. Thank you for the help.